# mysql query optimization (using sum function )

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I have a situation that i have used below query to retire usage of certain user but problem is that now mysql sums all the records from the table. Instead of getting sum of all records i just to want to stop query when the sum is greater than 500. I have tired 3 different ways. Can anyone suggest me which is the best way to achieve the result.

1st version query

```
 SELECT
(SUM(radacct.acctinputoctets) + SUM(radacct.acctoutputoctets))/8388608 AS total_usage
FROM `radacct`
WHERE username ='fktmbishals'
```

2nd version query

```
SELECT
if ((SUM(radacct.acctinputoctets) + SUM(radacct.acctoutputoctets))/8388608 > 500   , 500, 0) AS total_usage
FROM `radacct`
WHERE username ='fktmbishals'
```

3rd version query

```
SELECT
(SUM(temp_radacct.acctinputoctets) + SUM(temp_radacct.acctoutputoctets))/8388608 AS total_usage
FROM (
   SELECT
radacct.acctinputoctets,radacct.acctoutputoctets
FROM `radacct`
WHERE username ='fktmbishals'
LIMIT 10
) as temp_radacct
```

Comment: How many rows are in the table for that user?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel there are more than 10,00000 records

Comment: all your queries are doing something different....let us know what you want....may be there will be better option than you tried.

Comment: Whats wrong with the second query?

Comment: In 2nd query if think its adding all the records available and matching the conditions so it just going through summing all the records

Comment: And shouldn't it do that?

Comment: @sagi, it's a performance issue

Comment: just want to break the query when sum reaches 500  and i don't want mysql to add all unnecessary records

Comment: @Dipen, maybe you you write a loop in application site and get the sum step by step antil you get 500. First loop IDs from 1 to 10000, second loop IDs from 10001 to 20000 and so on.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel in my app i have already gone through 3 loops already. 1st retrieving user, 2nd all financial records related, 3rd user account related stuffs so now the record i am pulling is dependent with account so i will take lot of execution time.

Comment: If username field is indexed then your first query should work fine.....in other queries mysql even doing more work.

Comment: What indexes are defined? Better you post the table definition code.

Comment: I have indexed username,index Type => Normal, method =>BTREE

Comment: Try a compound index on (username, acctinputoctets, acctoutputoctets). You should also consider to replace the username column with user_id which would be a foreign key to the users table. This way you would keep the table and the index small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @tot := 0; 
SELECT  total_usage 
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  @usage := acctinputoctets + acctoutputoctets AS usage,
                @tot := @tot + @usage / 8388608 AS total_usage
            FROM  radacct
            WHERE username ='fktmbishals'
            ORDER BY  ?? 
      ) x
    HAVING  Total < 500;
```

That shows the running total until it exceeds 500.  Is that what you wanted?  Or did you want the last value?  If so, put that inside another query that uses `LIMIT 1`.

What `ORDER BY` do you need?

Don't you need to know what items make up the 500?

What do you want if the entire total is less than 500?

Comment: `SET @tot := 0; 
SELECT   temp.total_usage 
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  @usage_t := acctinputoctets + acctoutputoctets AS usage_t,
                @tot := @tot + @usage_t / 8388608 AS total_usage
            FROM  radacct
            WHERE username ='fktmdipenlama'
      ORDER BY
      @usage_t DESC
      ) as temp
    Having  total_usage < 500
  LIMIT 1 
 ;  ` @Rick James i did as you have said now when i include limit and order by the query runs slower 4.453s but without it runs faster.

Comment: query time without Limit and order by is 0.797s

Comment: Since there is no way to terminate a `SELECT` like yours prematurely, a full table scan is required.

Comment: Do you need the `ORDER BY`?  `ORDER BY  @usage_t DESC` does not work like you think.  Removing the `ORDER BY` avoids a sort.  `LIMIT 1` probably gets the one at the wrong end.

Comment: Thanks @Rick James now my queries are somewhat faster and how query optimization works if SELECT scans all the table if there are millions of records.

Comment: So what should i do to get only last value then.

Comment: "want to stop query when the sum is greater than 500" -- I understand that.  But what application needs that kind of data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107594/discussion-between-dipen-and-rick-james).

Comment: `SELECT MAX(total_usage) FROM ( the-existing-query ) AS x`.  But that just gives you a number less than 500.  What good is that?